# ggplot2 doesn't plots some data combinations on a worldmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to plot a list of cities,in the script labelled as "current_mapdata", on a worldmap with ggplot2.
For the worldmap,I'm using the package rnaturalearth

```
1  worldmap <- ne_countries(returnclass = 'sf', scale='medium') 
2  #Plot Worldmap within boundaries
3  update_geom_defaults("point",list(size=1))
4  ggplot() + geom_sf(data = worldmap, fill= "#71c6a6",lwd=0) +
5  #Problematic code line
6  coord_sf(xlim = c(long_min, long_max), ylim = c(lat_min,lat_max), expand = FALSE,     default_crs=NULL)+
7  geom_point(
8  data= current_mapdata,
9  aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)
10 )
```

But I get an error with following coordinates:

- lat_max: 57,92
- lat_min: -48,32
- long_max: 171,83
- long_min: -90,27

It seems, the error is in line 6 and I get the following message:

```
Error in st_cast.POINT(x[[1]], to, ...) : 
cannot create MULTILINESTRING from POINT
In addition: Warning message:
In st_cast.GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(X[[i]], ...) :
only first part of geometrycollection is retained
```

if I comment this line out, the script runs smoothly and without any error messages.
Has anyone an Idea what the problem is and would help me?

Comment: Can you show the lines where lat_max etc, are defined?

Comment: Have you tried without the `coord_sf()`? It seems a little redundant, since you are not defining any crs in that function

Comment: The code you provided does not reproduce - in particular the `current_mapdata` object does not seem to be defined. Its structure is crucial - is it a regular data frame, or a {sf} object? It is kind of difficult to form an opinion without having this information. Could you provide a working reprex (i.e. a piece of code that actually runs)?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
Finally I found my mistake.
I needed to change the following argument:
default_crs = NULL 
to
default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326).
In that way my data was intepreted as values in the  WGS84 system.
Could anyone explain, why the NULL argument doesn't work?
I thought, the NULL argument would also mean, that the data is intepreted and plotted in th WGS84 .

Comment: And sorry that I couldn't give any more information.
It's a script I wrote for my job, so I need to be careful, which Information I reveal.
But the reason why I use sf_coord is to zoom into the map.
I hope, that's helps you understanding the problem a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but after using this `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` I solved my problem